# ADB shell permission issues with python scripts: /data/local/tmp/iperf not found

Tags: android, python, linux, shell, adb

I am trying to execute iperf binary which is in /data/local/tmp/iperf of my android device (not rooted)  through python scripts and i am getting below error:

```
/system/bin/sh: /data/local/tmp/iperf  not found
```

But when I tried running manually through adb -s $device-id  shell "command" it is successful.  I had tried giving permissions to the tmp folder as well as iperf binary.

Directory permissions for device are listed below:

```
#adb -s D1CGAPE750402265 shell ls -ld /data/local/tmp
drwxrwx--x 2 shell shell 4096 2017-11-20 18:51 /data/local/tmp
# adb -s D1CGAPE750402265 shell ls -ld /data/local/tmp/iperf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 shell shell 4176160 2017-11-21 11:19 /data/local/tmp/iperf
# adb -s D1CGAPE750402265 shell ls -ld /data/local/
drwxr-x--x 3 root root 4096 1970-02-17 21:58 /data/local/
# adb -s D1CGAPE750402265 shell ls -ld /data/
drwxrwx--x 49 system system 4096 1970-02-17 21:58 /data/
# adb -s D1CGAPE750402265 shell ls -ld /
drwxrwxrwt 24 root root 2380 1970-07-16 13:14 /
```

Comment: Did you try giving absolute path?

Comment: yes, i have tried giving absolute path ie /data/local/tmp/iperf but no result. I tried cd to /data/local/tmp  and tried executing, but my path is not changing it is still in /

Comment: Okay, so you running user and owner of python script are "shell"? Reason I am asking is that, if owner and user of python script are different than "shell", then such script will fail. If you're comfortable, please give the code snippet in your question, that will help.

Comment: /usr/bin/adb -s XXXXXXXXXX shell nohup sh -c "cd /data/tmp/local;./iperf" > /tmp/dbg5 2>&1

Comment: if i remove nohup i am successful in running the command inside device.